# How to call ACF field in functions?

Tags: advanced-custom-fields

I'm working on a website and am trying to fix how they set up their meta tags, but am having a bit of trouble.

The current way its set up is that all pages have the og:image set to a logo. I want two post types (post-1 and post-2) to show their respective image contained through ACF.

See below how it looks.

```
 <?php
function insert_fb_in_head() {
global $post;
if ( !is_singular())
return;
echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="NewWays"/>';
if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) {
$default_image="https://logoURLgoeshere";
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
}
else{
$thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
}
echo "
";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 ); 
?>
```

They way they set it up with the exclamation marks in "is_singular" and "has_post_thumbnail", *every single page* on the site ends up getting that code written for the meta.

I'm fine with it for non-post-1 and post-2 pages, but how do I add another if statement to write the image as the meta for og:image?

I tried to add this but it doesn't help. Anyone have any ideas?

```
function insert_og_image() {
if ( is_singular( 'post-1', 'post-2'))
$featuredImage = get_field('image');
echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $featuredImage . '"/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use && for AND or could us || for OR so the if statement would be if (is_singular('post-1') || is_singular('post-2')){};

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try. I check for the circumstance you want on the outer part of the condition, then fallback to the other (old) behavior as it was before. This has the least potential to screw with things elsewhere site-wide, while also accounting for your special case.

```php
<?php
function insert_fb_in_head() {
    global $post;

    if ( !is_singular())
    return;

    echo '<meta property="og:title" content="' . get_the_title() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:type" content="article"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:url" content="' . get_permalink() . '"/>';
    echo '<meta property="og:site_name" content="NewWays"/>';

    if(is_singular(array('post-1', 'post-2'))) {
        $featuredImage = get_field('image');
        echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $featuredImage . '"/>';
    }else{
        if(!has_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )) {
            $default_image="https://logoURLgoeshere";
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . $default_image . '"/>';
        }else{
            $thumbnail_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'medium' );
            echo '<meta property="og:image" content="' . esc_attr( $thumbnail_src[0] ) . '"/>';
        }
    }

    echo "
    ";
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'insert_fb_in_head', 5 );
```

Hope this helps. Best of luck!

Comment: This actually is working, but now I ran into another problem - the echo just writes out "Array" instead of the actual data in the field. From reading online people say you need to tell ACF where to grab the values from by using "get_the_ID()" next to the "image" in get_the_field. I tried this but still doesnt work. Any ideas?

Comment: Fixed it by adding the "URL" selector instead: get_field('image')['url']